# error: multiple definiton of class function c++

Tags: c++

## Bar.h

```
#ifndef BAR_H
#defind BAR_H

class Foo;

class Bar
{ 
    Bar();
    virtual ~Bar();

    public:
        const Foo* getP();
        const Foo  getS();
        int        getW();
        void       setValues (Foo* m, Foo n, int o);

    protected:
        Foo* p;
        Foo* s;
        int w;
};
#endif
```

## Foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class Bar;

class Foo
{
                 Foo(int key, std::string str);
    virtual      ~Foo();
    int          id;
    std::string  inst;

    public:
        std::vector<Bar*>   getBars();
        std::vector<Foo*>   getP();
        std::vector<Foo*>   getS();

    protected:
        std::vector<Foo*> p;
        std::vector<Foo*> s;
        std::vector<Bar*> e;
};
#endif
```

## Bar.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Bar.h"

Bar::Bar()
{
    w=0;
}

Bar:~Bar() {}

void Bar::setValues(Foo* m, Foo* n, int o)
{
    p=m;
    s=n;
    w=o;
}

const Foo * Bar::getP()
{
    return p;
}

const Foo* Bar::getS()
{
    returns;
}

int Bar::getW()
{
    return w;
}
```

## Foo.cpp

```
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include "Foo.h"

    Foo::foo(int key, std::string str)
    {
        id   = key;
        inst = str;
    }

    Foo::~Foo() {}

   std:vector<Bar*> Foo::getBars()
    {
        return e;
    }

    std::vector<Foo*> Foo::getP()
    {
        return p;
    }

    std::vector<Foo*> Foo::getS()
    {
        return s;
    }
```

I have spent 2 days researching what I could. I followed the following
- No *.cpp's in headers or include statements
- Only declarations in header's
- Definitions in *.cpp
- tried adding #include "Foo.h" in Bar.cpp -> didnt help
- tried adding #include "Bar.h" in Foo.cpp -> didnt help
- Tried above two steps simultaneously -> didn't help

Am now pressed for tim, could really use help. Thank you

Comment: Please paste the exact, complete linker error message you get. And there are a couple of little mistakes in this code that should error on the compile step, not the link step: is this really a cut and paste from something you tested and saw the same error message?

Comment: No, I was not able to cut and paste so I entered it by hand. It is should be close thought. so if there are errors please, please let me know.

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have two functions with the same name even if they return different values. Try giving getS() a different name in one of the classes.

Also, if these classes are not inherited by other classes then you need not make the destructors virtual.

Comment: I changed the name of the functions with the same names in Foo to be different than Bar. That did not work. Same error

Comment: This is silly. Names in different scopes (and each class is a scope) do not conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Check this line in **Bar.h**:

`void setValues (Foo* m, Foo n, int o);`

and then this one in **Bar.cpp**:

`void Bar::setValues(Foo* m, Foo* n, int o)`

Then headers doesn't match, you must declare `Foo n` as `Foo*` in your `.hpp`